# How to check if WMI Query returned 0 rows?

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm working on a C# code that is obviously wrong.
I'm trying to get a pendrive data with WMI query and after continuing with the operations, check if the query returned 0 rows to avoid bugs.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_USBDevice");
ManagementObjectCollection drive = searcher.Get();
if (drive == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to read data.");
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Obviously the `drive == null` method does not work. How can I check it the proper way?
And also, is this the proper way of getting a pendrive data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it foolproof:

```
if (drive==null || drive.Count == 0))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Failed to read data.");
   Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Worked well, thanks. I thought it's not working because of another mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132433(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (drive.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to read data.");
    Application.Exit();
}
```